# Building a new column in a dataframe. Replacement has 0 Rows, data has X.

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of US Zipcodes, and am trying to attach a new column with state and city from the zipcodes database, and can't seem to get around the following error. I have tried numerous ways, but always end up at the same place.

[image: Data]

```
lUsers$Zip <- as.character( lUsers$Zip )
lUsers$city <- filter( zipcode, zip ==  lUsers$Zip )$city
```

This yields the following error.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `filter` selection is selecting 0 rows by the looks of it. Try running each part separately without doing any `<-` assignment and see if you are getting what you expect.

Comment: Following up, I can run it with filter( zipcode, zip ==  lUsers$Zip[1] ) , Without the indexer, I get an error message in zip with th "longer object length is not a multiple of a shorter object length"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line:

```
lUsers$city <- filter( zipcode, zip ==  lUsers$Zip )$city
```

will try to compare corresponding rows in `lUsers` with rows of `zipcode`, like doing `zipcode$zip == lUsers$Zip`, ie element by element.

You probably want to do a left-join, something like:

```
lUsers = left_join(lUsers, zipcode, c("zip"="Zip"))
```

which will match the rows in `zipcode` to the rows of `lUsers` and add the columns. Drop the columns you don't need afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, the left join works rather neatly, however, I am still confused. 

Isn't comparing the two exactly what I want to do? So filtering out the row in zipcode that has the corresponding zip from lUsers, then returning just the city element?

Comment: As you wrote it, it compared row 1 in lUsers with row 1 in zipcode. No match. then row 2 in lUsers with row 2 in zipcode. No match... And so on until it gets to row 543 in zipcode and you only have 542 rows in lUsers so it goes horribly wrong...

Comment: Ah, I see completely, I assumed it would have compared row1 in lUsers with row2 in zipcode, then row1 from lUsers with row2 in zipcode. Many thanks mate.

Comment: Not quite, it would compare row 1 in lUsers with row 543 in zipcode. Try playing with stuff like `c(1,2,3,4,5) == c(1,3,4)`

Answer (score 0):

NOT RUN, but try:

```
citystate <- zipcode[ , c(1:3)]
for (i in 1:nrow(lUsers){
for (j in 1:nrow(citystate)) {
if (lUsers[i, 5] == citystate[j, 1])
lUsers[i, 6] <- citystate[j, 2]
}
}
```

Repeat to get the state by changing the last line to:
    lUsers[i,7] <- citystate[j,3]

Hope this suggestion isn't a luser!! Lol.

Comment: You should arrange lUsers according to Zip to make the loop run quicker and smoother...just a suggestion.